# Polynomial summation to zero

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a polynomial $f(n)$ defined by $f(n) = n^2 * (n + 1)$ where $n \in W$ (whole number 0,1,2 ..)

I have to somehow manipulate its term to zero i.e.

$a * f(n) + b * f(n-1) + c * f(n-3) \cdots + i * f(n-k) = 0$

How to find $a, b, c \cdots i$ in above equation. $a,b,c \cdots i \in I$

Note : This relation is a part of other recurrence relation. So I am trying to remove the $n$ terms to make it the recurrence free of $n$

Comment: This isn't a recurrence relation?

Comment: What is the set $I$?

Comment: @user1936752 Integer

Comment: @PeterForeman Sorry my bad. It is a polynomial. Right?

Comment: It's a cubic polynomial, so its fourth difference is zero: $f(n)-4f(n-1)+6f(n-2)-4f(n-3)+f(n-4)=0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How? Can you give some resources regarding this?

Comment: For any polynomial $f$ of positive degree, $f(x)-f(x-1)$ will be a polynomial of smaller degree ...

Comment: Are you imposing the equality of the two "$i$"s in $if(n-i)$?

Comment: @user10354138. My bad.  I am very sorry. those i are not related. I will change the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

We have the backward difference operator
$$
\nabla\colon f \mapsto (n\mapsto f(n)-f(n-1))
$$
maps a polynomial of degree $d$ to a polynomial of degree $\leq d-1$.  Since your starting $f(n)=n^2(n-1)$ is a polynomial of degree $3$, we have $\nabla^4 f=0$, i.e.,
$$\label{eq1}
f(n)-4f(n-1)+6f(n-2)-4f(n-3)+f(n-4)=0\text{ for all }n\tag{1}
$$
But the coefficient of $f(n-4)$ is $+1$, not $+4$.  We can fix this either by multiplying \eqref{eq1} by 4
$$
4f(n)-16f(n-1)+24f(n-2)-16f(n-3)+4f(n-4)=0
$$
or by adding 5 times
$$\label{eq2}
f(n-1)-4f(n-2)+6f(n-3)-4f(n-4)+f(n-5)=0\tag{2}
$$
to equation \eqref{eq1}, yielding
$$
f(n)+f(n-1)-14f(n-2)+26f(n-3)-19f(n-4)+5f(n-5)
=0.
$$